# Spring JPA entity manager returns no rows after bulk insert inside transaction

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, bulkinsert

I have the following method

```
  @Transactional
  void method()
  {
      // JPQL bulk insert goes here

      //  JPA criteria query to select results of bulk insert above 
      // returns nothing here
  }
```

Why JPA doesn't see the new records after JPQL bulk insert?

Comment: maybe because you are not committing or flushing your bulk insert before querying again....

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities.  Here are some

1. in your query, you are doing it by calling some other component (e.g. a DAO), for which the query method is declared to have new transaction (e.g. REQUIRED_NEW).  As it is in another txn, you will not be able to see the change until the "outer" txn is committed.
2. You have turned on 2nd level cache and query cache, so that the query is simply returning the result that is previously cached.
3. The way for you to get the entity manager is probably problematic, and you are using two EMs which bounds to different txns.
4. You query is simply wrong so that it return empty result

In order to aid your debugging, try to turn on SQL tracing (by log4jdbc/JdbcDsLog etc) and check what is the actual statement issued to DB.